# Restore ZFS automount

Tags: kernel, compiling, zfs

I've upgraded to 15.04 and I found the package `ubuntu-zfs` to be broken on `systemd`.

I found the [bug description on GitHub](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/issues/145) but I don't know how the procedure to be done as described:

> The correct way to solve this (which I've done in my Wheezy packages), is to build-depend on dh-systemd and then call dh_systemd_enable and dh_systemd_start in the debian/rules file. That will install the systemd files in the correct place, in the correct package AND create the correct stanzas in the post/pre inst/rm files.

Somebody could help me in doing this? I tried searching but I don't find anything of what they are talking about. :D

Big Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier if you followed [martinpitt's comment](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/issues/145#issuecomment-86575770) and the one after it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions refer to building Debian packages. You need to follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs#developer-build-instructions), but before running `git-buildpackage`, edit the `control` file in the `debian` directory ([`debian/control`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/blob/master/ubuntu/vivid/debian/control)) and add to the `Build-Depends` list, `dh-systemd` (add it anywhere in the list, really, but I like keeping the order):

```
Build-Depends: autotools-dev,
 autoconf,
 autogen,
 automake,
 debhelper (>= 8),
 dh-autoreconf,
 dh-systemd
 dkms (>= 2.2.0.2),
 libselinux1-dev,
 libtool,
 uuid-dev,
 zlib1g-dev,
```

Then edit the `rules` file in the `debian` directory ([`debian/rules`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/blob/master/ubuntu/vivid/debian/rules)) and:

- change [the overall `dh` command](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/blob/master/ubuntu/vivid/debian/rules#L12) to:

  ```
  dh $@ --with autoreconf,dkms,systemd
  ```
- delete the [`override_dh_installinit`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/blob/master/ubuntu/vivid/debian/rules#L92) section.

When you add `systemd` to the `--with` options, `dh_systemd_enable` and `dh_systemd_start` will be called at the right time.

Also, in addition to the other packages already mentioned in `Build-Depends`, you will have to install `dh-systemd` (`sudo apt-get install dh-systemd`).